# Read variable value from another jar

Tags: java

I want read variable value from another jar

*Main.jar*

```
public static int version = 2;
```

I already did add libraries navigate to Main.jar (lib/Main.jar)

then I do this from Loader.jar

```
int version = dummy.Main.version;
```

Do replace with a new one if there are update

*Loader.jar*

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/cn/Main.jar");
        try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("lib/Main.jar"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        catch (HeadlessException | IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
                   //do exception
                } 
         }
```

But the problem is i can not replace file because the file is being used, since Main.jar is used by Loader.jar

How the solution to replace the file being used ?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options

- close the program using it and try again after restarting.
- create a new JAR file each time and load it in a different class loader each time.
- read the contents of the class in the JAR using a byte code reader such as ASM.
- instead of storing the version in code, store it in a file (or as well). You can easily read the file from a JAR without putting it on the class path.
- run `javap` to dump the code for the static field and extract the value from the text.

I suspect the last option is easiest to code.

Comment: how to extract the value then implementation into my code using javap ?

Comment: @IrfanFauzi you can run java using runtime exec and read/parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't replace the JAR file, because you cannot safely force the other process to not be using it.

Instead, install the newer JAR file next to it, with the version number embedded in the JAR file name, and rewrite your other users of the JAR file to periodically scan for newer JAR files.  When finding one, they should throw away the class loaders that loaded the old JAR files, and reload the new set.

Or, decide not to embed this information in a JAR file at all.  Resource files are easier to read and dispose of than JAR files, and they are plain text files.